# How to add days to pandas datetime until x day is met?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

For example I have a pandas dataframe of names and dates:

```
    name       date
0    Tom 2021-12-05
1    Sue 2021-11-22
2  Steve 2021-10-17
```

I'm trying to round each date up to the 25th (not the nearest) to look like this:

```
    name       date
0    Tom 2021-12-25
1    Sue 2021-11-25
2  Steve 2021-10-25
```

My most recent attempts looks like this:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='d') if x['date'].dt.strftime('%d') != '25' else x['date'])
```

I think my issue stems from being able to first check what the 'day' is and then add days until the 25th day is satisfied. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
jezrael's answer solves the problem while also factoring for dates beyond the 25th and is concise.

I also found this to work as well:

```
from pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas import Timedelta

def next_date(input_date):
  while (input_date.day != 25):
    input_date = input_date + Timedelta("1 day")
  return input_date

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].dt.date)
df['next_start_ship'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: next_date(x))
```

Comment: Whats happens if there is `2021-12-30` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need replace all days to `25` use:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-25'))
```

Or:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=25))
```

---

```
print (df)
    name       date
0    Tom 2021-12-25
1    Sue 2021-11-25
2  Steve 2021-10-25
```

If need replace only days until `25`, else is added 1 month and also set to `days=25` use:

```
print (df)
    name        date
0    Tom  2021-12-05
1    Sue  2021-11-30
2  Steve  2021-10-17


mask = df['date'].dt.day < 25

s = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-25'))
df['date'] = np.where(mask, s, s + pd.DateOffset(months=1))
print (df)
    name       date
0    Tom 2021-12-25
1    Sue 2021-12-25
2  Steve 2021-10-25
```

Comment: Almost too easy, thank you! If one of my dates was the 31st and I wanted that one to be the 25th of the following month, is there a similar approach to achieve this?

Comment: @mastrshayk - so if days are greater like `25` is necessary add one month and set days to 25? So `2021-11-30` to `2021-12-25` or `2021-11-26` to `2021-12-25` ?

Comment: @mastrshayk - If yes, then use `df['date'] += np.where(mask,pd.DateOffset(day=25), pd.DateOffset(months=1, day=25))`

Comment: @mastrshayk - Added solution to answer.

Comment: Very cool, thank you so much. 
`def next_date(input_date):
  while (input_date.day != 25):
    input_date = input_date + Timedelta("1 day")
  return input_date

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].dt.date)
df['next_start_ship'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: next_date(x))`
I found this to work as well. But your answer I believe is more concise.